# Bootstrap: auto-sizing and centering odd number of columns with column break

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap (v5) row with 9 columns. For `lg` and larger screens, I want 5 before and 4 after a column break, I want the 5 first to autosize to the entire width of the row and the the last 4 to have the same column size as the first 5. The last 4 columns should be aligned to the center. How do I accomplish this?

A non-working example is as follows

```
<div class="container pt-4">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg p-3">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg p-3">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg p-3">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg p-3">Col 4</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg p-3">Col 5</div>
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg p-3">Col 6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg p-3">Col 7</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg p-3">Col 8</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg p-3">Col 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The 4 last, after the column break, autosize too which makes them wider than the 5 first ones. I want them to have same size and the "left over" space to be placed equally on the sides, i.e., centering the 4 columns.

Note that smaller screen sizes have a 2 columns per "row" and that there should be no break between the 5th and 6th column in that layout (this works correctly in the provided example).